# Punctuation to denote more interest/excitement than a full stop, but less than an exclamation mark

Tags: punctuation, word-usage

Is  there a punctuation mark to express more interest/excitement than a full stop, but less than an exclamation mark? I ask this because it seems uncouth to end two sentences in a row with an exclamation mark, so the writer may come off as overly excited or mildly deranged.

Comment: Alternatives to an exclamation mark include switching font (bold, italics, etc.) or colour (if relevant to your context), and using capital letters. But generally speaking these would all be *more* emphatic anyway. I suggest you concentrate more on choosing the best *words* to express yourself clearly.

Comment: It really depends. If two totally weird or extraordinary things happen consecutively, the writere might be justified in being overexcited twice. If not, couldn't you just leave one of the punctuation marks out?

Comment: @SConroy In the situation that inspired this question, I had a simple observation that I felt didn't justify the use of an exclamation mark, but required a tonal direction one way or the other. A full stop felt jarring and had a much more negative tone to the prior sentence, which was undesired.

Comment: If this isn't very formal, you can reword one of your sentences into an arch observation and throw a question mark on.  "We just won the championship! After such a terrible showing last year, who would have thought we'd pull that off?"

Comment: It could be helpful to see an example -- if not the original then something analagous.

Comment: There are too many ways of answering this without an example sentence to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reasonable way around this is to first use a semicolon and then use an exclamation mark, as in these examples:

- I was thrilled; he bought me a pony!
- I couldn't believe they returned; I never thought I'd see them again!
- Finding the treasure was amazing; seeing that gold coin made my heart stop!

Comment: You've given such great examples!  :)